# WordPress - Pass get_option value to class variable

Tags: php, wordpress, class, variables, plugins

I am writing a WordPress plugin where I want to pass option value to class variable. Here is a class

```
class wpsmy_html_compression
{
    // protected $compress_css = ( get_option('wpsmy_combine_js') == 'on' ? true : false );
    // protected $compress_js = ( get_option('wpsmy_combine_css') == 'on' ? true : false );
    protected $compress_js = true;
    protected $compress_css = true;
    protected $info_comment = true;
    protected $remove_comments = true;

    // Variables
    protected $html;

    public function __construct($html)
    {
        if (!empty($html)) {
            $this->parseHTML($html);
        }
    }
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

Here is a call

```
function wpsmy_html_compression_finish($html)
{
    return new wpsmy_html_compression($html);
}

function wpsmy_html_compression_start()
{
    ob_start('wpsmy_html_compression_finish');
}

add_action('get_header', 'wpsmy_html_compression_start');
```

What I want is to pass dynamic values (true / false) using WordPress get_option to class variables `$compress_js` and `$compress_css`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a == operator to get the boolean? If get_option(...) == 'on'?

```
$compress_css = ( get_option('wpsmy_combine_js') == 'on' );
```

You can go to `/wp-admin/options.php`, to see the "real" value of the option. If it's 'on' or something else!

Comment: Sorry, I guess you've miscalculated. What I want is to pass value to `$compress_js` and `$compress_css` inside `class wpsmy_html_compression`. `get_option('wpsmy_combine_js')` and `get_option('wpsmy_combine_css')` has value `on` or `off`. I don't think that I need to go to `/wp-admin/options.php` to see the "real" value of the option.

Comment: You don't - But if the value is "on", compress_css should be `true`, with my code? I may misinterpret your question though!

Comment: If we leave `get_option(...)` aside for a while. How can I pass `false` or any other custom value to variable `$compress_js` and `$compress_css` inside `class wpsmy_html_compression`. `protected $compress_js = true;` is hard-coded at the moment.

Comment: And `protected $compreess_js = ( get_option('wpsmy_combine_js') == 'on' )` wouldn't work? Since `( get_option('wpsmy_combine_js') == 'on' )` evaluates to a boolean?